# JS function returns JSON. How can I return just the values?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, function

I have a function in Angular that is returning JSON. How can I just have it return the values?

Category Factory

```
angular.module('ExpenseApp')
        .factory('CategoryLoader', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('http://localhost:3000/categories', {
    });
})
```

function in Controller

```
CategoryLoader.query(function (response) {
        $scope.categories = response;       
});
```

This is what I get when I bind it to ng-model

```
"category":"{\"id\":\"2\",\"name\":\"Hotel/Transportation\"}"
```

This is what I want.

```
"category\":\"Hotel/Transportation\"
```

Comment: can you show JSON data which contains at least 2 categories?

Comment: This is the console.log(response)
Array[14]
0
:
m
id
:
"0"
name
:
"Entertainment-Big Ticket/Shared Entertainment"
__proto__
:
Object
1
:
m
id
:
"1"
name
:
"Entertainment General"
__proto__
:
Object
2
:
m
id
:
"2"
name
:
"Hotel/Transportation"
__proto__
:
Object
3
:
m
id
:
"3"
name
:
"Internet Connection"
__proto__
:
Object
4
:
m
id
:
"4"
name
:
"Management Meeting"
__proto__
:
Object
5
:
m
id
:
"5"
name
:
"Meals"
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: can you give that in your questions plz with formatting?, its really hard to read the array structure from above. what i understand your $scope.categories will hold various category but the JSON needs to be in a specific format so that some ui  component works ?

Comment: [
  {
    "id": "0",
    "name": "Entertainment-Big Ticket/Shared Entertainment"
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Entertainment General"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Hotel/Transportation"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Internet Connection"
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "Management Meeting"
  },
  {
    "id": "5",
    "name": "Meals"
  },
  {
    "id": "6",
    "name": "Mobile Communications (fax,cell)"
  },
  {
    "id": "7",
    "name": "Personal Vehicle Mileage"
  },
  {
    "id": "8",
    "name": "Postage"
  }
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate over the response and than assign the array to the scope:

```
categoriesarray=[];
for(var i=0;i<response.length;i++){
     categoriesarray[i] = "Category : " + response[i].name;
 }
 $scope.categories= categoriesarray;
```

Comment: I get an error "Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1" . I believe the response is already parsed (Angular does it?)

Comment: It did thank you. Below is the code with a small edit(Added $scope)

CategoryLoader.query(function (response) {
            
            $scope.categoriesarray = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                $scope.categoriesarray[i] = " " + response[i].name;
            }
            $scope.categories = $scope.categoriesarray;
            
        });

Answer (score 0):

> Format the data the way you like (see below) the set it to $scope.categories.

```
CategoryLoader.query(function (response) {
    var tmpCategories = [];
    angular.forEach(response, function(value, key) {
        console.log(key + ': ' + value);
        categories.push({category : value.name}); 
    }); 
    $scope.categories = tomCategories;       
});
```